# Python re pattern matching

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to solve a problem of regex identification using re module.
I would like to copy some lines beginning with * from a file, the exact line pattern is:

```
*7  3   279 0
```

and among the characters there are tabs.
My regex to match with the lines is:

```
regex=re.compile(r'^\*\d+.\n', re.MULTILINE)
for line in f:
    if regexp.match(line)
    print >> a, line
```

The script I wrote create the file 'a' but it is empty, it cannot recognise the pattern.
Have you got some advices?

Moreover, could you explain me the difference between a pattern in double quote and insingle quote? I searched in several python manual but I did not find any info.

Comment: In Python, there's no difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem like you need multiline matching if you're processing the input file line-by-line anyway. Use regular matching, and try searching for `$` instead of `\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are ONLY looking for `*`+number at the beginning of a line, you only need to do this:

```
regex=re.compile(r'\*\d+')
for line in f:
    if regexp.match(line)
    print >> a, line
```

If you care the number of numbers found delimited by spaces:

```
regex=re.compile(r'\*(?:\d+\s+){3}\d+')
for line in f:
    if regexp.match(line)
    print >> a, line
```

If you use `re.match` you don't need the `^` anchor. If you use `re.search`, you do. [See the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Answer (score 2):

You're not capturing the totality of the line with your regex, You'd only be matching lines of type:

`*7`

Something like `^\*(?:\d+\s+)+$` should work, no need for multiline since you're applying the regex to each line of the file.

Edit:
Changed to a non-capturing group, since it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 re.compile(r'^\*\d\s+\d+\s+')
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know python but it seems regex sgould be this `^[*][\d(\s)*]+$`